# Является ли тот факт что если в MySql таблице есть поле с типом json то это NoSql?

Tags: mysql, json, база-данных, nosql

Всем привет. Возник следующий вопрос, так как json это по нереляционным баз данных, а в MySql(который является реляционным) доступный тип данных json, то при добавлении такого поля в БД становится уже не нормализированной?

Comment: нет. Это всё равно что сказать: есть человек и свинья, но если пересадить человеку сердце свиньи, значит он становится свиньёй

Comment: о нормализации имеет смысл говорить, если вы с этими данными работаете в рамках запросов. Если вы эти данные (json) просто храните, не обращаетесь к их полям и отдаете во внешнюю среду, то это просто данные. (как  любая строка состоящая из букв, но мы же не говорим что не декомпозировали ее на буквы и их порядок?). В общем JSON это не "нереляционные базы данных", а в целом формат сериализации. Если на уровне объектов предметной области нам нет смысла декомпозировать эту сущность, то в нормализации таблица не теряет. Но в целом нормализация и NoSQL это вообще про разное.

Comment: Нормализация ничего не говорит о типе данных и никак не соотносится с ним. А потому хранение в JSON и нормализованность никак не связаны. И точно так же NoSQL никак не соотносится с типом данных, в котором данные хранятся.